# Than I am V.S than me

Tags: grammar, word-order

I have a question about this 2 options...I was talking with 2 friends about healthy and one of them said "You ´re are fitter than I am" .So my other friend said" No, it has to be than me not than I am"
I was very confused,so i wonder if you can explain me with this sentence...thank you :3

Comment: Actually, both are correct. But "than I am" sounds more formal.

Comment: Although figurative, both of these are also fine in terms of their grammar: (1) *You are crazier than **a box of loons**.* (2) *I am taller than **you are** short.* This is the same as in the question. You can make a comparison to an object (*me / a box of loons*) or to a subject and verb [and adjective] (*I am / you are*).

Comment: I was always taught that 'than I am' was correct.